# Scala Lazy Dynamic Programming

Tags: scala, dynamic-programming, lazy-evaluation

So I'm following http://jelv.is/blog/Lazy-Dynamic-Programming/ and implementing the Fibonacci example in Scala. Here is my implementation:

```
class Lazy[T] (expr : => T) {
  lazy val value = expr
  def apply(): T = value
}
object Lazy{ def apply[T](expr : => T) = new Lazy({expr}) }

def fib(n: Int): Int = {
  def doFib(i: Int): Lazy[Int] = Lazy {
    if (i <= 2) 1
    else fibs(i - 1)() + fibs(i - 2)()
  }
  lazy val fibs = Array.tabulate[Lazy[Int]](n)(doFib)
  doFib(n).value
}
fib(5)
```

In this case, `fib(5)` correctly returns result 5.
Then I want to see if `Lazy[T]` can be made into a monad by trying the following code, which results in StackOverflow runtime error:

```
class Lazy[T] (expr : => T) {
  lazy val value = expr
  def apply(): T = value
  def flatMap[A](f: T => Lazy[A]): Lazy[A] = Lazy { f(value).value }
  def map[A](f: T => A): Lazy[A] = Lazy { f(value) }
}
object Lazy{ def apply[T](expr : => T) = new Lazy({expr}) }

def fib(n: Int): Int = {
  def doFib(i: Int): Lazy[Int] =
    if (i <= 2) Lazy(1)
    else for {
      a <- fibs(i - 1)
      b <- fibs(i - 2)
    } yield a + b
  lazy val fibs = Array.tabulate[Lazy[Int]](n)(doFib)
  doFib(n).value
}
fib(5)
```

It appears that fibs(i - 1) is calculated too early, which results in infinite recursion. I wonder if there is a `for` comprehension syntax that's equivalent to the first code snippet?

Answer (score 3):

You are right, "fibs(i - 1) is calculated too early". It is evaluated immediately when you call `doFib`, because the `doFib(i)` needs `fibs(i - 1)` in order to be able to return anything, which in turn needs the return value of `doFib(i - 1)` and so on, so that the recursion unfolds completely while you are constructing the array of lazy ints (before you invoke `doFib(n).value`).

If you want it lazy, then return a `Lazy` that does not require immediate evaluation of `fibs(i - 1)`:

```
class Lazy[T] (expr : => T) {
  lazy val value = expr
  def apply(): T = value
  def flatMap[A](f: T => Lazy[A]): Lazy[A] = Lazy { f(value).value }
  def map[A](f: T => A): Lazy[A] = Lazy { f(value) }
}

object Lazy{ def apply[T](expr : => T) = new Lazy({expr}) }

def fib(n: Int): Int = {
  def doFib(i: Int): Lazy[Int] =
    if (i <= 2) Lazy(1)
    else Lazy{ (for {
        a <- fibs(i - 1)
        b <- fibs(i - 2)
      } yield a + b).value
    }
  lazy val fibs = Array.tabulate[Lazy[Int]](n)(doFib)
  doFib(n).value
}

println(fib(40)) // 102334155
```

Alternatively, you can wrap the whole `if-else` in a `Lazy`:

```
def doFib(i: Int): Lazy[Int] = Lazy {
  if (i <= 2) 1
  else (for {
    a <- fibs(i - 1)
    b <- fibs(i - 2)
  } yield a + b).value
}
```

This produces the same expected result.